# laravel 5.2 user login with active status

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

hi every one i am using laravel 5.2 default auth but i want that the user must only be logged in with active status.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

in this link they given the method like the following

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

but I did not find this  where it is located in laravel 5.2.

I searched but the solutions are for previous versions and not for 5.2.

So please help me to login the users that has active status only so give me laravel 5.2 not of 5.1  or previous versions built in or custom solution to solve the problem

Comment: it still works like that

Comment: This works with 5.2, did you try it?

Comment: They added it to the documentation to show that you can verify other fields on the user table. They used the `active` field as an example, Laravel doesn't come with account activation features out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default auth setup, you can override the `getCredentials` method on the `AuthController`, which comes from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

```
protected function getCredentials(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password') + ['active' => 1];
}
```

That method returns the credentials array that is passed to `Auth::attempt` in the `login` method of `AuthController`. As other people have mentioned you will need to have a `active` field on your `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

That example is only to show you can add custom fields when attempting to login.

You need to add an extra field to your User table like isActive.

When you have done this you can check if a user is active in your application.

```
if($user->isActive) {
 // do something
}
```